# arduino freezes when using array

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to run a simple code to check how I can update an array in a loop. But It is not working. It looks like the code freezes the arduino. Please suggest something.

```
int n[10] = {} ; // n is an array of 10 integers

void setup () {

}

void loop () {
   for ( int j = 0; j < 10; ++j ){ // output each array element's value {
      n[j] = j;
      Serial.print (n[j]) ;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all your code, then you are missing several necessary statements in the `setup()` function.   For example, you don't even set the rate of communication, so `Serial` has no idea what speed to transmit and receive at...

Simplest example:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {}
```

You'll need more than the few lines above, but there are thousands of examples available online to get you going.  Start with the example above and build on it.

[Reference: The Arduino Documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/)